# Disable a specific tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/uyxrqhex/

I need to disable the second tab and i have no clue how to do it.

For jquery-ui we can use `disabled: [1]` but i do not know if that will work with my demo and if will work, how to do it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please post relevant code here as well, not just a link to a fiddle. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your questions.

Comment: What's more relevant than a complete jsfiddle to see live the issue? Would it be better to throw here some lines of code and than you will have to make a jsfiddle? I doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a couple of changes. Added a "disabled" class to tab 2's `<li>` and changed your [jQuery to use .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It also now filters out the `.current` ***and*** `.disabled` classes.

**HTML for List**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="current">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="disabled">Tab 2</li>
    <li>Tab 3</li>
    <li>Tab 4</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul.tabs').on('click', 'li:not(.current, .disabled)', function() {
 $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
   .parents('div.section').find('div.box').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(150).siblings('div.box').hide();
```

})

Link here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5g4dyny/)

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you